# Python text formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

Need some help with Python string formatting 
I have two code:

```
a = "Hello"
b = False
p = "Python rocks"
q = True
```

I want to print a,b,p & q like this:

```
Hello ................................. False
Python rocks .......................... True
```

The total length of each line (From Hello to False) is fixed say 70 chars.

(edit) Following was being tried. Clearly not a good way (and incorrect), hence the question

```
arr = [ ["Hello", False], ["Python rocks", True]]
totallen = 70

for e in arr:
    result = "{0}".format(e[1])
    dottedlen = totallen - len(e[0]) - len(result) - 2
    dottedstr = "." * dottedlen
    str = "".join([e[0], " ", dottedstr, " ", result])
    print str
```

Comment: `q` is `False`, yet you expect it to print `True`?

Comment: In your expected output the first line contains 45 chars and second contains 44?

Comment: Its my mistake in the description. The output mentioned is the one I need. Its the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
In [48]: def solve(a,b):
    a,b=str(a),str(b)
    spaces=len(a.split())-1
    return "{0} {1} {2}".format(a,"."*(68-len(a)-len(b)-spaces),b)
   ....: 

In [49]: print solve(a,b);print solve(p,q)
Hello .......................................................... False
Python rocks ................................................... True
```

Comment: @user2248790 they're aligned, see you expected output you posted in the question body.

Comment: No, your output does not match your function. Replace `(68 - len(a) - len(b)` with `(69 - len(a))` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP said that the total length of the string is fixed , but even his expected output contains unequal number of characters. He must clarify this first.

Comment: True, the wording is ambiguous, but the output formatting example is clear enough.

Comment: Accepted this as answer: simple. does the job and pythonic!

Answer (score 0):

just create a function to add the periods up until your fixed amount of characters:

```
def formatter(my_string,length,my_boolean):
    my_string += " " + "." * (length - len(my_string))
    print my_string, my_boolean
formatter(a,70,b)
formatter(p,70,q)
```

note: the reason for having print instead of return, is when you have return and then print it, using this method it prints the following:

```
('Hello .................................................................', False)
('Python rocks ..........................................................', False)
```

but without return and just printing it directly from the function gives you what you want:

```
Hello ................................................................. False
Python rocks .......................................................... False
```